# How can I exclude one or more drives (hard drives) from my search when searching in My PC in an explorer window in Win10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

I want to search my local hard disks and my removable USB thumb drives while excluding my Google Drive (G:). I'm trying to search using an explorer window using the search box (F3). My location bar is set to My PC.

What I've tried:

(a) unindexing the G: drive. I've checked my Search Indexing options and the G:\ drive is not included.

(b) excluding the folder in the "Searching Windows" options (launched from Win+S ; windows search options). In the Excluded Folders section, I click the the Add and excluded folder button and select the G:\ folder (I've also tried a subfolder in there) and then the folder doesn't get added to the list. If I try adding a folder on a different drive (C:\Source) it shows up in the list.

I'm guessing the solution would be some special search syntax involving the path and Not. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: after checking my indexed locations, I'm still seeing bad search results. But I believe I've got the answer. Currently, my search index is being rebuilt. With the G: drive excluded. At this point:

When I try the search query: size:>1000000 ext: mp4 path: NOT g:*

I get results only on the C: drive as pictured here

[search_results_qty_25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlDIQ.png)

But when I try the search query: size:>1000000 ext: mp4

I get results on the C: and G: drive as pictured here

[search_results_including_C_and_G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp3cy.png)

I think that Google Drive for Desktop has special behavior that makes itself included in the explorer search, despite indexing options and Windows Search Excluded Folders options, and can only be excluded in the query string.

Comment: Have you done everything listed in [this article](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/hide-files-folders-from-search-windows-10/)? Are you searching for file-names or content?

Comment: I checked the indexed locations of my computer and the G:\ was not among them. But I added a couple thumb drives while I was in there and also elected to rebuild the search index. After that I believe I was still seeing bad search results. But later, I was experimenting with search syntax and currently am seeing very limited results so it's possible that the search reindex will do the trick. I'm trying to find redundant content by filename, but currently my test query string is (without quotes) "size:>1000000 ext: mp4 path: NOT g:\*"

Comment: To sum that up, yes, I tried what that article mentioned and it's yet unclear whether I've succeeded :) Thanks for your response

Comment: Rebuilding the index may take time, so it's normal for things to improve gradually. If you're unhappy with Windows Search, there exist also good third-party free tools.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually determined that I can exclude drives from searching in "This PC" by using search terms such as the following.

(NOT (path: C:*)) AND (NOT (path: G:*) AND (kind: video) AND (size: >100000000) AND ((name: orange) OR (name: purple))